# Notepad++ Modify shortcuts to run PHP pages at localhost

Tags: notepad++, shortcut

i want to modify shortcuts.xml file in notepad++ directory to change commands in

- Run > Launch in Firefox
- Run > Launch in IE
  etc

i change following line

```
<Command name="Launch in Firefox" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="88">firefox &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
```

to

```
<Command name="Launch in Firefox" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="88">firefox &quot;http://localhost/$(FILE_NAME)&quot;</Command>
```

But when i restart Notepad++ modified lines become reset. 
How to save these shourtcuts?

Answer (score 2):

`shortcuts.xml` file gets overwritten when Notepad++ is closed. Use a different editor and save your changes when Notepad++ is not running. See [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Configuration_File_Editing).

Answer (score 1):

1. Close Notepad++
2. Edit shortcuts.xml in notepad (i.e. NOT
   notepad++)
3. Reopen Notepad++